# Rotate elements in a list using a for loop

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following list.

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

I want to replace (rotate) each element using a for loop. In the first step, the first element is rotated. In the second step, the first two elements are rotated. Then after 4 steps of the loop, the output should look like:

[image: example after 4 steps]

I tried several options, for example:

```
ReplacePart[data, 
 Thread[data[[1 ;; 3]] -> Rotate[data[[1 ;; 3]], 90 Degree]]]
```

But this replacement doesn't give me the output I want. How can I perform this sequence of rotations?

Comment: The question arises: what for?

Comment: …Well, why do you mention for loop? You don't even use it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a for loop:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} ;
size = Length[data] ;
table = {} ;
For[
  i = 1,
  i <= size,
  i++,
  data[[i]] = Rotate[data[[i]], 90 Degree] ;
  AppendTo[table, data] ;
] ;
Grid[table, Frame->All]
```

Answer (score 7):

Will this work? Or do you have to use Thread? How about using a loop?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
newData=First@Last@Reap@Do[
   z=Rotate[data[[#]],90 Degree]&/@Range[n];
   Sow[Join[z,data[[n+1;;]]]],
{n,1,Length@data}
];
Grid[newData,Frame->All]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
f = ReplaceList[ {a__, b___} :> Join[Map[Rotate[#, π/2] &]@{a}, {b}]];

f @ data // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Take[f @ data, 5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a function with two arguments specifying the input list and desired number of rows to take:

```
ClearAll[g]
g = ReplaceList[{a__, b___} /; Length[{a}] <= #2 :> 
      Join[Map[Rotate[#, π/2] &] @ {a}, {b}]] @ # &;


g[data, 7] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Let's package up a function to rotate a given number of elements in a list:

```
RotateElems[count_, list_] := MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, list, List /@ Range@count]
```

Now we can generate a table of partially rotated lists:

```
Table[RotateElems[i, data], {i, Length@data}]
```

You can use `Grid` for display if you want:

```
Grid[Table[RotateElems[i, data], {i, Length@data}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

You could add an argument to `RotateElems` to specify the amount of rotation.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

Rest@FoldList[MapAt[Rotate[#,90 Degree]&,#1,#2]&,data,Range[4]]//MatrixForm
```

[image: Matrix of results as tiff]

**As a Grid**

```
Grid[Rest@FoldList[MapAt[Rotate[#,90 Degree]&,#1,#2]&,data,Range[Length@data]],
     Frame->All]
```

**Another way**

```
Rest@FoldList[ReplaceAt[#1,x_->Rotate[x,90 Degree],#2]&,data,Range@Length@data]
  //Grid[#,Frame->All]&
```

**Just for Fun**

```
MapAt[Rotate[#,90 Degree]&, data,Transpose[{#}]]&/@Range@Range@Length@data
  //Grid[#, Frame->All]&
```

Or

```
ReplaceAt[data,x_->Rotate[x,90 Degree],Transpose[{#}]]&/@Range@Range@Length@data
  //Grid[#,Frame->All]&
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way using `LowerTriangularize`:

```
rotateMat[lst_?VectorQ] := Module[{mat, pos},mat = ConstantArray[lst, Length[lst]];
pos = Join @@ (Position[LowerTriangularize[mat], #] & /@ lst);
ReplacePart[mat, Thread[pos -> Map[Rotate[#, π/2] &, Extract[mat, pos]]]]]
```

For example:

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

rotateMat[data] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution with `SubsetMap`:

```
f[expr_Rotate] := expr
f[expr_] := Rotate[expr, 90 Degree]
SetAttributes[f, Listable]

With[{n = 10, step = 5}, SubsetMap[f, Range@n, ;; #] & /@ Range@step] // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Shoutout to @E. Chan-López for the idea to use `*Triangularize`.

```
data = ConstantArray[Range[10], 10];
rotatedData = Map[Rotate[#, \[Pi]/2] &, data, {-1}];
LowerTriangularize@rotatedData + UpperTriangularize[data, 1] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest way:

```
Table[If[i >= j, Rotate[j, 90 Degree], j], {i,1,5}, {j,1,8}] // Grid
```

[image]